Construct Suzuki 2-groups in GAP system
A Suzuki 2-group is a nonabelian 2-group $G$ with the following properties:
(1) $G$ has more than 1 involution.
(2) $G$ has an odd-order automorphism $\phi$ such that $\langle \phi\rangle$ acts transitively on
the subset of involutions $\{ x\in G: o(x)=2 \}$.
According to G. Higman's classification of Suzuki 2-groups, we have four types of Suzuki 2-groups. Namely, A, B, C, D.
For instance, if $G$ is of B-type, we use the symbol $G=B(n,\theta, \epsilon)$.
The underlying set of $G$ is $\mathbb{F}_q \times \mathbb{F}_q\times \mathbb{F}_q$ where $q=2^n$ and $\mathbb{F}_q$ is the finite field of $q$ elements,
the multiplication is defined as follows:
$$(a,b,c)\cdot(d,e,f)=(a+d,b+e,c+f+ad^\theta+\epsilon ae^\theta+be^\theta),$$
where $\theta\in \mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{F}_q)$ has odd order, and $\epsilon\neq x^{-1}+x^\theta$ for all $x\in \mathbb{F}_q$.
My question is: given $n,\theta, \epsilon$, how to construct such a Suzuki 2-group in GAP system?

This may help: https://forum.mail.gap-system.narkive.com/WDc0NncC/gap-suzuki-2-groups#post1

Also, apparently Magma has a built-in function to construct Suzuki 2-groups

The gap codes for constructing Suzuki 2-groups of A-type are very helpful. Thanks very much!
